# Получить количество соответствий AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

Хочу изменить цвет текста, если нет совпадений. Как узнать количество отображенных айтемов `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: Если вы считаете, что вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его правильным (галочка слева)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить количество элементов в списке можно через метод адаптера `getCount()` (`getItemCount()`), в зависимости от типа адаптера.